# Finding value of residual

Tags: statistical-significance, least-squares

Consider the LSR line: y = 1158.86 - 5.54x

A researcher sought to examine the effect of average teacher salary on the average (total) SAT score.  The data, measured at the state level so 50 observations in total, were average teacher salary (measured in thousands of dollars) and average SAT scores out of 1600 points (the old SAT format).

Alabama has an average teacher salary (in thousands of dollars) of 31.14 and an average SAT score of 1029.  Based on the least squares regression line, what is the value of the residual for the state of Alabama?

Can someone explain what the residual is?  How do I calculate what it is in this case?  Why do they give me information about Alabama specifically (i.e. the salary *and* score)?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: If this is for some subject could you please add the `self-study` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Think about what a residual is:

Residual = Observed value - Predicted value

$e$ = $y$ - $\hat{y}$

What is the observed value here?

What is the predicted value (from the regression formula)?